# python - How to properly encode string in utf8 which is ISO8859-1 from xml

Tags: python, xml, encoding, utf-8

I'm using the following code in python 2.7 to retrieve an xmlFile containing some german umlauts like ä,ü,ö,ß:

```
.....
def getXML(self,url):
    xmlFile=urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
    xmlResponse=xmlFile.read()
    xmlResponse=xmlResponse
    xmlFile.close()
    return xmlResponse
    pass

def makeDict(self, xmlFile):
    data = xmltodict.parse(xmlFile)
    return data

def saveJSON(self, dictionary):
    currentDayData=dictionary['speiseplan']['tag'][1]
    file=open('data.json','w')
    # Write the currentDay as JSON 
    file.write(json.dumps(currentDayData))
    file.close()
    return True
    pass

 # Execute
 url="path/to/xml/"
 App=GetMensaJSON(url)
 xml=GetMensaJSON.getXML(App,url)

 dictionary=GetMensaJSON.makeDict(App,xml)
 GetMensaJSON.saveJSON(App,dictionary)
```

The problem is that the xml File claims in its `<xml>` tag that it is utf-8. It however isn't. By trying I found out that it is iso8859_1 
So I wanted to reconvert from utf-8 to iso8859 and back to utf-8 to resolve the conflicts.

Is there an elegant way to resolve missing umlauts? In my code for example I have instead of ß`\u00c3\u009f` an instead of ü`\u00c3\u00bc`

I found this similar question but I can't get it to work [How to parse an XML file with encoding declaration in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390213/how-to-parse-an-xml-file-with-encoding-declaration-in-python)

Also I should add that I can't influence the way I get the xml.

The XML File Link can be found in the code.

The output from ´repr(xmlResponse)´ is

```
 "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n<speiseplan>\n<tag timestamp='1453676400'>\n<item language='de'>\n<category>Stammessen</category>\n<title>Gem\xc3\x83\xc2\xbcsebr\xc3\x83\xc2\xbche mit Backerbsen (25,28,31,33,34), paniertes H\xc3\x83\xc2\xa4hnchenbrustschnitzel (25) mit Paprikasauce (33,34), Pommes frites und Gem\xc3\x83\xc2\xbcse
```

Comment: Why would you do that? XML files document what codec they use in the headers.

Comment: And the `urllib2.urlopen()` returns **encoded bytes**, not Unicode, so you can't encode that.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly the problem.  The xml says its UTF-8 but it isnt.  I have added an extract from it above.

Comment: If you have broken (Mojibake) data in your XML document, fix that after parsing the XML. It'd be far more helpful though, if you could provide us with a sample XML snippet plus code that shows what you are parsing and how.

Comment: Could you share the output of `repr(xmlResponse)` instead? That'll give us a Python string literal that'll contain `\xhh` escape sequences that make it far easier for us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to encode *already encoded data*. `urllib2.urlopen()` can only return you a bytestring, not `unicode`, so encoding makes little sense.

What happens instead is that Python is trying to be helpful here; if you insist on encoding bytes, then it'll decode those to `unicode` data *first*. And it'll use the default codec for that.

On top of that, XML documents are themselves responsible for documenting what codec should be used to decode. The default codec is UTF-8, don't manually re-code the data yourself, leave that to a XML parser.

If you have [Mojibake data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in your XML document, the best way to fix that is to do so after parsing. I recommend the `ftfy` package to do this for you.

You *could* manually 'fix' the encoding by first decoding as UTF-8, then encoding to Latin-1 again:

```
xmlResponse = xmlFile.read().decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1')
```

However, this makes the assumption that your data has been badly decoded as Latin-1 to begin with; this is not always a safe assumption. If it was decoded as Windows CP 1252, for example, then the best way to recover your data is to still use `ftfy`.

You could try using `ftfy` *before* parsing as XML, but this relies on the document not having used any non-ASCII elements outside of text and attribute content:

```
xmlResponse = ftfy.fix_text(
    xmlFile.read().decode('utf-8'),
    fix_entities=False, uncurl_quotes=False, fix_latin_ligatures=False).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks the solution with ftfy worked perfectly. I did a last encode('utf-8') to have the xml in utf-8.   Otherwise file.write() wouldn't let me save it.